# Neo4j 2.0 dump with double type

Tags: neo4j, dump

On Neo4j 2.0 (community) when I dump a db with some nodes with Double type properties, I obtain a file with value in scientific notation : ex 1.43524185E8

On import of this file, the neo4j-shell fail with the following error :

```
Invalid input 'E': expected Digit, whitespace, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, ',' or '}' (line 167, column 153)
"create (_30015:`organization`:`fr` {`capital`:1.43524185E8, })"
                                                         ^
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.parser.CypherParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(CypherParser.scala:53)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.parser.CypherParser$$anonfun$parse$1.apply(CypherParser.scala:43)
```

It seem Double type are not correctly parsed.

Command used for dumping the db :

```
$ neo4j-shell -c "dump" > ito3.graph
```

Command used to import them (in an empty graph.db) :

```
$ neo4j-shell -file ito3.graph
```

Detail of affected properties :

```
neo4j-sh (__value_deleted__,30015)$ ls -v
...
*capital                  =[1.43524185E8] (double)     
...
```

Comment: I think this is a bug with the dump command, can you report an issue at github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues ?

Comment: done : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1781

Comment: @MichaelHunger i just had a similar issue with escaping quotes in string values. Property names are back-ticked, but a value like `string "value"` is dumped as `"string "value""` which breaks on import. Is this an issue with dump or am I doing it wrong? Never used the dump command until I saw @bastien 's interesting example.

Comment: Nevermind, found the github issue addressing it

Answer (score 1):

In java generally, scientific notation numbers don't parse to doubles.   [Here's a related forum posting describing how to use DecimalFormat to fix the issue](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-theory-questions/6467-parsing-scientific-notation-string.html).

I think the bottom line is that what you're giving cypher isn't a double, but a string, and since you're not putting quotes around the string, it's dying.   You need to give it a valid numeric format there.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
But I confirm this is a Double type (I check that with a ls -v in neo4j-shell).
If it can't be parsed in a double type, despite the orignal value was in Double type, then I think there are a problem with dump / import functions in Neo4j 2.0

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you're doing the dump?  It appears as though somehow, your large value doubles are getting turned into scientific notation when you do the dump.  There might be options for adjusting this, but you have to first understand how the dump is happening, and what configuration options are present there.

Comment: As indacated in my post :
`$ neo4j-shell -c "dump" > ito3.graph`