# Neo4J Cypher recomendation app

Tags: neo4j, cypher, recommendation-engine

My question is not that complicated, but i can't find an answer.

The picture below shows the result i have so far. The blue circle is the node that was my starting point. What i want to find is the nodes in the red circle minus the blue one! (the node(s) that has the most nodes in common with the starting node)

[image]

It's an app that recommends pieces of art based on what you like.. Based on colors, type, artist ect.

Here is my code for the result in the picture:

```
START Art=node(8986)
MATCH P=(Art)-[r:HAS_COLOR]->(Color)<-[:HAS_COLOR]-(Art1)
RETURN P, count(DISTINCT P) as Rel
ORDER BY Rel DESC
```

Hope it is understandable and that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to `MATCH` all other pieces of art that share colors (at least one) with you starting point. For recommendation you want to sort them by the number of shared colors.

This query should do what you need:

```
// start as you did before
START art1=node(8986)
// MATCH art1 to other art pieces via similar_color
MATCH (art1)-[:HAS_COLOR]->(similar_color:Color)<-[:HAS_COLOR]-(art2) 
// only if art1 is not the same as art2
WHERE art1 <> art2
// return art2 and the number of similar colors
RETURN DISTINCT art2, count(DISTINCT similar_color) AS num_sc
// order by simiar colors
ORDER BY num_sc DESC
```

A few notes:

- the `id` of a node can change (e.g. after deleting a node the `id` will be reused), you might want to consider replacing your `START` with a `MATCH`
- I would always use labels for matching nodes (i.e. `art2:Artpiece`)
- convention for Cypher queries is to use initial caps for `Labels` and preferrably not for `variables` (http://nigelsmall.com/zen)

Comment: Thanks Martin. That was exactly what i was looking for! Works like a charm :D

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should help you:

```
START Art=node(8986)
MATCH (Art)-[:HAS_COLOR]->()<-[:HAS_COLOR]-(Art1)
WHERE id(Art1) != id(Art)
RETURN Art1
```

I'm matching every node that has same colors as `Art`, and `WHERE` the given node is not `Art`.

I did not test this query because I don't have your dataset. If you have any troubles with it, I'll edit it.

Adding a dataset to your question could be awesome too :)

Comment: It doesn't work. It just returns all nodes that has a relation to the same color.
I don't know how to export my database in Neo4J :P

Comment: Isn't it what you are looking for (nodes with same colors relations)? Here is how to export your database : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830686/export-whole-database-in-cypher-format-ascii-text

Answer (score 0):

```
MATCH (art:Art) WHERE id(art)=8986
MATCH (art)-[:HAS_COLOR]->(c:Color)
MATCH (c)<-[r:HAS_COLOR]-(rec:Art)
WHERE NOT art=rec
WITH rec, count(r) AS num
RETURN rec, num ORDER BY num DESC
```

This should return other `Art` nodes, sorted by the number of common colors with `Art` with id 8986.

Comment: I think you have a typo: `WHERE id(art) > id(rec)` should be `WHERE id(art) <> id(rec)`, right?

Comment: Ah good point. I changed to use `WHERE NOT art=rec` which I think is more clear.

Comment: This one doesn't return anything :) The answear below does the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Does this query do what you want?

```
START art=node(8986)
MATCH (art)-[r:HAS_COLOR]->(c:Color)
MATCH p=(c)<-[:HAS_COLOR]-(art1)
WHERE art1 <> art
RETURN p, count(DISTINCT p) as rel
ORDER BY rel DESC;
```

It should return the same results, except for the `art` node (and all its `HAS_COLOR` relationships).