# Neo4j -- How to synchronize local database with remote neo4j database server

Tags: neo4j, data-synchronization, transactional-replication

I am working on a project where we are using Neo4j as a database. I have a remote database built for the application and hosted in Cloud. There is another database (local database) which is hosted at Client's location.

The ask is: Is there a way to synchronize the two database? Are there any direct COTS products which can be used for this synchronization?

Comment: I think this is a valid question but I believe you should remove your bolded sentence as it runs directly afoul of one of our off-topic reasons: asks for an off-site resource or product recommendation.

Comment: This is all I know of which might help you, and it won't help as much as you'd probably like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830686/export-whole-database-in-cypher-format-ascii-text

Answer (score 2):

While this may be an older question that might no longer concern Anish Bapna, I'd still like to provide an answer in case it proves valuable to anyone else who ends up here.

I faced a similar challenge when I needed a solution to compare and synchronize a Neo4j development database with a Neo4j production database in the past. Despite conducting multiple searches over the span of several years, I never came across a satisfactory solution.

Since Anish Bapna asked in a response to joe: “Is there a simpler way rather or some tool available to do it?” I feel it is relevant that at the outset of this year, I created my own Neo4j graph comparison tool that can do exactly what is being asked for. It goes by the name "Compare41" and can be accessed at [https://www.circles-arrows.com/](https://www.circlesarrows.com/).

To maintain full transparency, in case it wasn't evident, I have a close affiliation with Circles Arrows.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what version your running. 
If you use Enterprise Edition you can synchronize out of the box, however if you use Community you have to do it yourself.

I do this by recording all queries which modify data on the local database and then replay on the remote database.
The code below is an example of doing this in c#

```
 var query = _client.Cypher
                .Match("(p:Person)")
                .Where((Person p) => p.Id == id)
                .Set("p = {person}")
                .WithParam("person", person);
            query.ExecuteWithoutResults();
            RecordQuery(query);

private static void RecordQuery(dynamic query)
        {
            var syncStore = new SynchronisationStore();
            var replayQuery = syncStore.Create();
            replayQuery.TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            var queryText = query.Query.QueryText.Replace("\r\n", " ");
            replayQuery.CypherQueryText = queryText;
            replayQuery.CypherQueryParameters = query.Query.QueryParameters;
            syncStore.Store(replayQuery);
        }
```

You can then use whatever method you want to transfer the string data between servers (I use a RESTful service) and replay using:

```
public void ReplayQuery(ReplayQuery replayQuery)
        {
                foreach (var pair in replayQuery.CypherQueryParameters)
                {
                    replayQuery.CypherQueryText = replayQuery.CypherQueryText.Replace("{" + pair.Key + "}", SerializeWithoutQuote(pair.Value));
                }
                var query = new CypherQuery(replayQuery.CypherQueryText, new Dictionary<string, object>(), CypherResultMode.Set, null);

                _client.Connect();
                ((IRawGraphClient) _client).ExecuteCypher(query);
            }
        }
```

NOTE - you need to make sure you only replay once and that you replay queries in order.

Comment: Is there a simpler way rather or some tool available to do it? I have community edition version 3

Comment: I don't know of any tool which can do this for you. So its either do it yourself or fork out the astronomical cost of Neo4j Enterprise. With the code above and some mechanism of storing the replay queries as strings, and a flag to say whether synchronisation has been successful (I use MongoDB) you should be up and running within a day or so.